# Is the Max Function in SQL Server Sargable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, optimization

I am working on improving the performance of an SQL stored procedure that runs slowly.

Generally I am trying to optimise the execution plan that the query uses. My question involves the below snippet of SQL; is this SQL sargable in particular the `Max` function?

```
   SELECT MAX(Audit_Date) AS DATE,
          FK_RegisterID
     FROM dbo.[Audit Result Entry Detail]
    INNER 
     JOIN dbo.[Audit Register]
       ON dbo.[Audit Result Entry Detail].FK_RegisterID = dbo.[Audit Register].PK_ID
    WHERE ((SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Audit_Date))) >= @StartDate 
      AND  (SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Audit_Date))) <= @EndDate)
      AND part_number IN (@ParticipantNumber)
    GROUP 
       BY FK_RegisterID
```

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: Sargable applies to filters. Such as the `WHERE` clause, which in your case is not sargable. Not aggregates.

Comment: I would start by changing your `WHERE` clause to something like `Audit_Date >= @StartDate AND Audit_Date < DATEADD(dd,1,@EndDate)` so that you can benefit form an index on `Audit_Date` or a compound index on `Audit_date, part_number`.

Comment: You can lose the inner `Select` near the `DATEADD` - it's not necessary,  If you are using SQL Management Studio then I would recommend using **Include Actual Execution Plan** from the **Query** menu.  This will provide you with good information to revise your query and also show if you are missing an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments they where much helpful. I found this online which has also helped me understand how to make my SQL query more sargable.

> The typical situation that will make a SQL query non-sargable is to
>   include in the WHERE clause a function operating on a column value.
>   The WHERE clause is not the only clause where sargability can matter;
>   it can also have an effect on ORDER BY, GROUP BY and HAVING clauses.
>
> The SELECT clause, on the other hand, can contain non-sargable
>   expressions without adversely affecting the performance.

Comment: Yes - this is what @DStanley's comments were about, although I have heard (not tested) that SQL Server is now much better at automatically rearranging these internally